# ScaleOut Software In Memory DataGrid Using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, real-time, data-processing, scaleout-hserver

I have been doing some reading on real time processing using hadoop and stumbled upon this http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/hserver/

From what the documentation says, it looks like they implemented an in memory data grid using the hadoop worker/slave nodes. I have couple of questions here

1. From my understanding, if i have a data of size 100 GB, i would atleast need 100GB of ram across all nodes on my cluster just for the data + additional ram for task tracker, data node daemons + additional ram for the hServer service that would run on all these nodes. Is my understanding correct?
2. The software claims they can do real-time data processing by improving the latency issues in hadoop. Is it because, it allows us to write data to the in-memory grid instead of HDFS?

I am new to Big Data technologies. Apologize if some of the questions are naive.

Answer (score 2):

*[Full disclosure: I work at ScaleOut Software, the company which created ScaleOut hServer.]*

1. In-memory data grids create a replica for every object to ensure high availability in case of failures.**The aggregate amount of memory that is required is the memory used to store the objects with the addition of the memory used to store object replicas.** In your example, you will need 200 GB of total memory: 100 GB for objects and 100 GB for replicas. For example, in a four-server cluster, each server needs 50 GB of memory available to the ScaleOut hServer service.
2. With the current release, ScaleOut hServer takes the first step in enabling real-time analytics by speeding up data access. It does this in two ways, which are implemented using different input/output formats. The first mode of operation uses the grid as a cache for HDFS, and the second uses the grid as the primary storage for a data set, providing support for fast-changing, memory-based data. **Accessing data using an in-memory data grid reduces latency by eliminating disk I/O and minimizing network overhead.** Also, caching HDFS data provides an additional performance boost by storing keys and values generated by the record reader instead of raw HDFS files in the grid.